# "No such file or Directory" but I'm in the directory with the file

Tags: c, cs50

I'm trying to work on this problem for CS50 but for some baffling reason it won't even acknowledge that the file I'm trying to run even exists when I'm in the right directory with said file.

[image: env]

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Check for command line args
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./read infile\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Create buffer to read into
    char buffer[7];

    // Create array to store plate numbers
    char *plates[8];

    FILE *infile = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    int idx = 0;

    while (fread(buffer, 1, 7, infile) == 7)
    {
        // Replace '\n' with '\0'
        buffer[6] = '\0';

        // Save plate number in array
        plates[idx] = buffer;
        idx++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", plates[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you compile your program successfully? It isn't that your program isn't loading the file it is that your program does not exist with the name `license`.

Comment: I would suggest to `ls -l licence`.

Comment: Best to check `if (!infile) { perror ("fopen-infile"); return 1; }` before attempting to read from the file-stream.

Comment: Instead of a screenshot, it would be better to post a *textual* representation of your directories and their contents. [`pwd`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pwd.1.html) and [`ls`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) can be used to create examples of this data. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2505965)

Comment: "but I'm in the directory with the file" Your screenshot clearly shows that there is no `license` file in that folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`license.c` is a *source* file, that must be *compiled* into an *executable* file. `license` is not the same as `license.c`.

The CS50 tool for turning source files into executable files is called `make`. For example, executing `make foo` will cause the program to look for a source file called `foo.c` and produce an executable called `foo`, assuming no errors occur during compilation (or linking).

This is described in the [Week 1 Lecture](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/weeks/1/), and in various other places, such as [*Debug*](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/problems/1/debug/).

In summary, type the following commands in order.

```
$ make license
$ ./license
```

The `$` indicates you are typing these commands into a terminal.

---

As for your program:

- `infile` should be tested to not be `NULL`. If it is `NULL`, the program should probably exit early, otherwise `fread` will invoke [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).
- In `plates[idx] = buffer;`, `buffer` decays to a pointer to its first element, and this pointer value is stored in the `plates` array. There is no copying of the buffer elements, or automatic memory allocation taking place. In effect, you are repeatedly storing a reference to the **same** array in `plates`.

  - You should allocate memory in some way to store every plate you read. Either with dynamic memory allocation, or a *two-dimensional* array (e.g., `char plates[8][7];`). With the former you will want to copy (`strcpy` / `memcpy`) the values of the current buffer to the new memory allocation, and with the latter you can read directly into `plates` instead.
- The `while` loop should additionally check that `plates` is not full before reading more data from the file. Otherwise, when `idx` is greater than or equal (`>=`) to 8, you will invoke more [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) by accessing `plates` at an out-of-bounds position.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command to compile your source file into a binary with the filename *license*.

```
gcc license.c –o license
```

The -o flag allows you to specify a output filename. If you do not use the -o flag, an output file with the name *a.out* will be generated.

Now you can use `./license` to execute your code.

Comment: Always compile with *warnings enabled*, and **do not** accept code until it *compiles without warning*. To enable warnings add `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` to your `gcc/clang` compile string (also consider adding `-Wshadow` to warn on shadowed variables and `-Werror` to treat warnings as errors). For **VS** (`cl.exe` on windows), use `/W3`. All other compilers will have similar options.